# How to echo a JSON output

Tags: php, json

Below is the JSON code i got after logging in with Facebook. How can extract data from this JSON ? I tried the following ones, but not working.

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

stdClass Object ( [id] => 725426940865193 [email] => stargijo2@gmail.com [first_name] => Gijo [gender] => male [last_name] => Varghese [link] => https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/725426940865193/ [locale] => en_GB [name] => Gijo Varghese [timezone] => 5.5 [updated_time] => 2014-09-27T13:47:05+0000 [verified] => 1 ) 

echo $user['email']; //not working
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an *object*, not an array. You need to use object syntax:

```
echo $user->email;
```

If you want to access it as an array you must pass `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode()`:

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url), true);
echo $user['email'];
```

Comment: @stargijo if it solves your problem make sure to click the check mark next to the answer to mark it as accepted.  It helps future readers of this question, the user that took the time to answer and your rep.